# IntelliJ Idea 12 - turn off the pop up window (ctrl + space)

Tags: intellij-idea

I don't know what's up my IntelliJ Idea 12, but all of a sudden it start showing this dialog whenever I press `ctrl+space` to see the members of a type (Scala, but I guess it doesn't matter):

[window](http://makescreen.ru/i/2f62a7840ed990c1e4f6048d05801c.jpg)

How do I turn it off?

Comment: And what happend if you type Ctrl+Q ?

Comment: please check the 'Autopopup documentation in (ms)' option value in Settings/Editor/Code completion - is it on? If it's off, check the shortcuts assigned to 'Quick documentation' action in Settings/Keymap/Main menu/View

Comment: did you able to solve this?

Comment: Check the [second answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155182/android-studio-ctrl-space-opens-documentation-window). This disables the documentation popup.