# android studio ctrl + space opens documentation window

Tags: android, android-studio

I have updated my Android Studio to the newest version, but now when I call the auto-completion/suggestions with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> the suggestion box opens but the documentation window opens as well.

Has anyone experienced this and know how to disable the opening of the documentation window?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Ctrl-Q toggles between doc window states (when using the default keymap).

Possible states are:

```
-Hidden
-Shown to the side of the auto-complete list
-Docked as one of the tabs
```

If you have a different keymap, you can search for this action in Settings -> Keymap. The action is called "Quick Doc".

Comment: Both CTRL-Q and CTRL-SPACE seem to open the Documentation window!? BTW I'm using Ubuntu

Comment: Once the auto-completion window is open, you can cycle through the states of the documentation window by pressing `Ctrl+Q`. The last doc window state will be remembered for next time the auto-completion window opens.

Comment: I disabled the 'auto-show button in the documentation window now everything works fine, thanks for the help

Comment: @wasp256 That doesn't work for me on the OSX version, it's off by default.

Comment: @daniel-gabriel The OSX shortcut equivalent (F1) doesn't work for me, though if I click on the gear icon on the top right of the quick doc window and, uncheck "Pinned Mode" and check "Floating mode" it at least appears as a small window to the right of the code completion suggestions. UPDATE: I take it back, your suggestion does work. If you don't cycle through the states, the little window stays there after you have finished with code completion.

Comment: This is the right answer,  keep press Ctrl-Q, and try each state till you get a auto hide documentation window, then every thing works again.

Comment: This is not the answer. `Keep pressing Ctrl-Q`, that's not a solution. see the below answers, disabling the autopopup of doc window is the right way.

Comment: This does not help in the new version.

Answer (score 111):

I'm using Android Studio 0.8.1 on OSX and have been experiencing the same irritating behavior.

The answer by @daniel-gabriel was not was I was looking for.

A better solution seems to be to go to `Preferences > IDE Settings section > Editor > Code Completion` (in AS 1.2.2 located in `Preferences->Editor->General`) and unticking the option **Autopopup documentation in (ms):**

[image]

Comment: Adding one more point to @Nirrek's valuable answer,  

To change the default keymap on Windows and Linux, go to File > Settings > Keymap  https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html#key-commands

Comment: This is the real solution not the other one.

Comment: Just had the same issue of AS 1.2.2 (OS X). Code completion is now found under Preferences->Editor->General

Comment: This is the correct answer and worked for me, good grief, such annoying behaviour to deal with when developing

Answer (score 36):

For ubuntu 14.04 :
**File > Settings > Editor > General >  Code Completion**

And unticking *Autopopup Documentation* will hide it.

Comment: on Mac OS:
Android Studio->Preferences->Editor->General->Code Completition

Comment: I still prefer the accepted answer, since it keeps easy documentation acess but makes it unintrusive.

Answer (score 20):

For **Windwos** && **Linux** (ubuntu) :

```
File > Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion
```

For **Mac** :

```
Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > General > Code Completion
```

---

**1.    unChecked : AutoPopup documentation (in CodeCompletion)**

**2.    unChecked : AutoPopup  (in Parameter Info)**

---

[image]

Comment: My popup window just hides after a second. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OSX, to restore the Documentation window to an auto-hide popup, toggle the popup window toolbar to checked state, from the popup windows gear icon, and then click "Restore Popup" icon in the documentation window toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the quicker solutions...

```
Press Ctrl + Space and let the "Documentation" window pop-up.

1) Click on the Settings icon and uncheck all the options except "Docked Mode".
2) Now push documentation window to the right, so as to make it invisible.

With this even though with press of "Ctrl + Space", internally command will pass 
to open the Documentation Window but it will not be visible and interfere with the 
workspace.
```

[image: Documentation Window - Android Studio]

I hope that helps. Happy Coding...

Comment: If you wish to improve the answers provide sensible reason for the negative markings.