# Android Studio doesn't auto generate code

Tags: android, android-studio

Why my Android Studio doesn't auto generate code

EX: I have to type all words `findViewById` because when I type `find`, the Android Studio doesn't hint me any code?? so I have to type all words!
When I type `.` after an constant it doesn't show anything!

Can someone help me?

Comment: You Should check this solution....

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18157209/4915547

Comment: Got to settings>Editor>General>Code completion and enable "Basic completion" and "Autopop code completion"

Comment: OK! Already solved this problem! Tks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press `ctrl+space` to show hints.
Also check the options under `File->Settings->Editor->Code Completion`