# Make IntelliJ documentation (quick-doc) window close when mouse is moved away

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

In Eclipse, when you hover over a variable, method, etc, you get a pop-up window with the documentation. When you move the mouse off of it, it disappears.

I can simulate the first part in Android Studio (IntelliJ) with the setting to enable quick-doc on hover. At first, this behaved exactly like Eclipse. However, I then clicked the 'pin' button on one of the windows because I wanted an extended look at a particular piece of documentation. Since then, after disabling Pinned Mode on that window, I now have to click away to close the quick-doc pop-up. Simply moving the mouse away from it doesn't close it anymore.

How do I restore this functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found out how to do it - just click the big red cross on the task bar - NOT the usual one to close a window in the top-right.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Uncheck the ***Autopopup documentation in(ms)*** option from ***Preference-> code completion***

Check this answer it may help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157209/3020568

[image: documentation]

Try changing the Documentation mode- it is also useful (uncheck floating mode)

Comment: That doesn't fix it I'm afraid. So if I hover over a method name, it'll bring up the documentation box as expected. If I move the mouse away, the box stays there and doesn't go away - I have to click to make it disappear still.

Comment: Are you sure you changed the Autopopup documentation in(ms) not  Autopopup in(ms)

Comment: Yeah :( Why would something under 'code completion' settings change this anyway though? I'm referring to the pop-up you get when hovering over an already-typed method or variable (ctrl-q if quick-doc on hover isn't enabled)

Comment: @Alex pls check updated answers. have a look. it may help you

Comment: Removing floating mode is the best alternative - I would prefer it to work as a pop-up that disappears (like the error pop-ups for example still do) but I can get used to the docs being at the side, cheers