# Android Studio annoying popup window for layout_width and layout_height

Tags: android, android-studio, android-popupwindow

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3 on Mac. Whenever I add a new element in a layout resource XML, the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes are auto-completed and the cursor jumps to the value of `layout_width` (which is fine).

The problem is that after a very short time, without doing anything, a popup window with the documentation of `match_parent` or `wrap_content` appears, and I have to close this window manually before I can enter my value for `layout_width`. The cursor then jumps to `layout_height` and the same procedure repeats all over again. This is extremely annoying when adding new views.

**Can anybody repeat this problem, or does anybody know a way to prevent it?**

Below is a GIF animation of the problem:

[image: Annoying documentation popup]

Comment: You can unselect the "pin" button that is in the top right of the popup window

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the issue but cltr + q pressing repeatedly will make the dialog dismissable. for mac i think its command + q

Comment: @lal This seems to be a good solution. In this way there is still a small popup window, but you don't need to close it to be able to continue typing. You could make this an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preferences > Editor > General > CodeCompletion > uncheck Auto popup feature

[image]

Comment: Unchecking "Autopopup documentation in (ms)" solves the problem. Another solution is "unpinning" the popup window, see comments for the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "Quick Doc"

Ctrl-Q (Command + Q , on MAC) toggles between doc window states (when using the default keymap).

Possible states are:

```
-Hidden
-Shown to the side of the auto-complete list
-Docked as one of the tabs
```

If you have a different keymap, you can search for this action in Settings -> Keymap. The action is called "Quick Doc".

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157209/5993410)

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify whether

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> "Other" section... "Show Quick Documentation on mouse move" is Unchecked?

Here is a visual for the same:
[image: Show Quick DOcumentation]

Answer (score 0):

For Windwos && Linux (ubuntu) :

`File > Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion`

For Mac :

`File > Preferences > Editor > General > Code Completion`

**unChecked : AutoPopup documentation**